# Row button con Grid JS

Tags: javascript, nodejs, grid

Hola a todos estoy usando [Grid Js](https://gridjs.io/), Leí su [documentación](https://gridjs.io/docs/examples/row-buttons) para poder implmentar el uso de botones dentro de las filas pero no he logrado conseguirlo.

El codigo donde implemento la librería esta en un archivo llamado main.js independiente y los links donde hago referencia a los archivos de la libería en mi pagina estan al inicio dentro de head para el css y al final en una etiqueta script,

```
<!-- Css -->
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/gridjs/dist/theme/mermaid.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<!-- JS -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/gridjs/dist/gridjs.umd.js"></script>
<script type="module"  src="js/frontend/main.js"></script>
```

Hasta aquí todo bien uso la liberia y no tengo ningun problema, pero para poder utilizar botones en las filas despues de leer la documentación no estoy muy seguro de donde y como importar las funciones que se solicitan .

```
import { Grid, h } from "gridjs";
```

Esta linea la he puesto al inicio de mi archivo main.js donde ejecuto el codigo para renderizar la tabla.

```
import { Grid,h } from "gridjs";
new gridjs.Grid({
            columns: [{name: 'id',},{name:'nombre',},'Razon',"Tipo","Num. SAP","Estatus",{ 
                name: 'Editar',
                formatter: (cell, row) => {
                  return h('button', {
                    className: 'py-2 mb-4 px-4 border rounded-md text-white bg-blue-600',
                    onClick: () => alert(`Editing "${row.cells[0].data}" "${row.cells[1].data}"`)
                  }, 'Edit');
                }
              }, 
            ],
            data: r,
            pagination:{
                limit: 10,
                summary: false
            }, 
            search: true
          }).render(document.getElementById("table_proveedores"));
```

Pero obtengo este error

"Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "gridjs". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".

Alguien sabe como solucionar este error.
Gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El import no esta funcionando, mejor llama las funciones desde **gridjs**, por ejemplo en lugar de **Grid** o **h**, llama a **gridjs.Grid** y **gridjs.h** respectivamente. Aquí puedes ver un ejemplo funcional con datos que invente para llenar la tabla.

```js
const r = [  [1, 'Juan', 'Razon 1', 'Tipo 1', '123', 'Activo'],
  [2, 'Maria', 'Razon 2', 'Tipo 2', '456', 'Deshabilitado'],
  [3, 'Pedro', 'Razon 3', 'Tipo 1', '789', 'Activo']
];

new gridjs.Grid({
            columns: [{name: 'id',},{name:'nombre',},'Razon',"Tipo","Num. SAP","Estatus",{ 
                name: 'Editar',
                formatter: (cell, row) => {
                  return gridjs.h('button', {
                    className: 'py-2 mb-4 px-4 border rounded-md text-white bg-blue-600',
                    onClick: () => alert(`Editing "${row.cells[0].data}" "${row.cells[1].data}"`)
                  }, 'Edit');
                }
              }, 
            ],
            data: r,
            pagination:{
                limit: 10,
                summary: false
            }, 
            search: true
          }).render(document.getElementById("table_proveedores"));
```

```html
<!-- Css -->
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/gridjs/dist/theme/mermaid.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<!-- JS -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/gridjs/dist/gridjs.umd.js"></script>
<script type="module"  src="js/frontend/main.js"></script>
<body><div id="table_proveedores"></div></body>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias.